# Export mysql table to CSV file not working

Tags: php

I got the output printed in the browser,while i need to download it as CSV file.
Below is my code

```
$output        = "";
$table         = ""; // Enter Your Table Name 
$sql           = mysql_query("select * from $table");
$columns_total = mysql_num_fields($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  for ($i = 1; $i < $columns_total-1; $i++) {
    $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
  }
  $output .="\n";
}
```

// Download the file

```
$filename = "myFile.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $output;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you generating the CSV file manually? There is a built in function for that; [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

```
<?php

// generate csv
$table = 'my_table';
$output_file = 'file.csv';
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';
$h = fopen($output_file, 'w');
$sql = mysql_query("select * from $table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    fputcsv($h, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}
fclose($h);

// force download csv
header("Content-type: application/force-download"); 
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'. $output_file .'"'); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-length: ". filesize($output_file)); 
header('Content-Type: application/excel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $output_file .'"');

?>
```

p.s. If you require the table column in the csv as headers, you can do this instead when generating the csv file:

```
// generate csv
$table = 'my_table';
$output_file = 'file.csv';
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';
$h = fopen($output_file, 'w');
$sql = mysql_query("select * from $table");
$header_written = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    if (!$header_written) {
        fputcsv($h, array_keys($row), $delimiter, $enclosure);    
        $header_written = true;
    }
    fputcsv($h, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
}
fclose($h);
```

Comment: P.S. `mysql_*` is deprecated. You should look into `MySQLi` or `PDO`.

Comment: Still printing result in the browser not forcing download

Comment: My code only shows how to generate csv file from db result and force output as a download to browser. It does not have any connection code in there. Did you remember to add the db connection code in there? i.e. `mysql_connect` and `mysql_close`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
    function force_download($file)
    {
        $dir = ""; // directory path if any
        if ((isset($file))&&(file_exists($dir.$file))) 
        {
           header("Content-type: application/force-download");
           header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $dir.$file . '"');
           header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
           header("Content-length: ".filesize($dir.$file));
           header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
           readfile("$dir$file");
        }
    }//end function

    $filename = "myFile.csv";
    force_download($filename);
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem as well, no matter what combination of "header" I used.

The solution for me was because I had some HTML in my "download.php" file.
I guess if the browser detects any HTML, it will display the data in the browser instead of initializing the download.

Delete any HTML in your "download.php" file and leave only PHP--- it should work.